# Memcache get in php, single key and multiple key in one function?

Tags: php, memcached

I was reading the php documentation (See : [Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.get.php)), It says you can use `Memcache::get()` function for single or multiple request, Is it possible?

If yes, why we have `getMulti` method in `Memcached`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Memcache::get(array(...))` is the Memcache method to get multiple results at once.
`Memcached::getMulti()` is the Memcached method to get multiple results at once.

Note: Memcache is a totally different library/extension than Memcached.

Comment: I was aware of the fact that the method is inside Memcached, but I thought it was an extension. Now it's clearer. Because they are different thats why we have this abstraction